# ListViewの下の空白を消したい

Tags: ios, android, flutter

今、Columnの中にListViewを配置しているのですが、とてもListViewの下の空白が気になります。
これを消す方法はありますか？

Swiftでいうところの `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()//空白`
のようなものを想定しております。

現在のコードは以下のようになっております。

```
const data = [
      Text("item0"),Text("item1"),Text("item2"),Text("item3"),Text("item4"),
    ];
```

```
child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                child: Container(
                  child: Text("NAME",
                   style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20
                  ),),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("内容"),
                        ListView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: data,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 125),
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Home())
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text("決定する")
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

考え方を変えて
ListViewにLimitedBoxを利用し、maxHeightを与えることで解決しました。
ありがとうございます